# Format specific MySQL DateTime YYYY-MM-DD in C# with Microsoft Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, datetime

I get an error when insert record in MySQL database with Microsoft Entity Framerk.

Mi table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `preventive` (
  `IDPREVENTIVE` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DESCRIPTION` text,
  `DATA_CRE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `preventive_unique` (`CODICE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My model builder is

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Preventive>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Idpreventive).HasName("PRIMARY");

            entity.ToTable("preventive");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Codice, "preventive_unique").IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Idpreventive)
                .HasColumnType("mediumint(9)")
                .HasColumnName("IDPREVENTIVE");
            entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                .HasColumnType("text")
                .HasColumnName("DESCRIPTION");
            entity.Property(e => e.DataCre)
                .HasColumnType("date")
                .HasColumnName("DATA_CRE")
        });
```

When I try to insert a record

```
context.Preventives.Add(edt_prev);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I get an error beacuse my date is wrongly formatted by Entity Framework.

```
SET @p0='mytext', @p1='06/02/2024'
INSERT INTO `preventive` (`DESCRIPTION`,`DATA_CRE`)
VALUES (@p0, @p1)
```

but MySQL accept date in this format 'YYYY-MM-DD', and the correct istruction is

```
SET @p0='mytext', @p1='2024-02-06'
INSERT INTO `preventive` (`DESCRIPTION`,`DATA_CRE`)
VALUES (@p0, @p1)
```

Is it possible to tell entity framework how to format the date? For example

```
            entity.Property(e => e.DataCre)
                .HasColumnType("date")
                .HasColumnName("DATA_CRE")
                .HasConversion("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

I tried using a converter, but I can't get it to use when inserting records

Comment: I don't understand this question. Dates aren't sent to the database as strings. What CLR type is `DataCre`?

Comment: If your `DataCre` property is type `string`, why? Generally speaking, dates/times should always be stored using dedicated types, which means `DateTime` or possibly `DateOnly` or `TimeOnly` in C#. Formatting is something that should generally be done at the point it's needed, e.g. if you're displaying a date in your UI, the formatting is part of the presentation logic. Apart from anything else, this allows you to display the same data in different ways, e.g. each user sees a date using the formatting rules for their own culture settings.

Comment: DataCre is "DATE" in MySQL

Comment: Yes, but what is the type in your C# code (the CLR type)?

Comment: @FabrizioCiavatta dates, both in .NET and MySQL, have no format, they're binary values. You didn't even post the error you got or your class. If `DATE_CRE` is indeed a `date`, you'd only have problems if the `DateCre` property is a string instead of DateTime. Or the *real* error is completely unrelated to what you posted. `.HasConversion("YYYY-MM-DD")` will only cause problems if the types are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting an error when Entity Framework tried to insert the element.

I resolved with this

```
var context = new PapiroDbContext()
var affectedRows = context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
    "INSERT INTO `preventive` " +
    "(DESCRIPTION, DATA_CRE) " +
    "VALUES(@DESCRIPTION, @DATA_CRE)",
    new MySqlConnector.MySqlParameter("@DESCRIPTION", edt_prev.Description),
    new MySqlConnector.MySqlParameter("@DATA_CRE", edt_prev.Data_Cre),
    new MySqlConnector.MySqlParameter("@COD_CLI", edt_prev.CodCli));
```

Answer (score 3):

As [ProgrommingLlama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/programmingllama) has stated in the comment.
Dates aren't sent to the database in the format you have provided.

I'm going to assume your `Preventive.DataCre` type is `string`.
In this instance you'll have to parse the string yourself and convert it how you'd like.

Comment: DataCre is DATE in MySQL

Comment: The fact that it's DATE in MySQL is irrelevant - what's relevant is what the .NET CLR type of `Preventive.DataCre` is. i.e. the problem isn't with your DB, it's with your application. Edit your question to include the class definition of `Preventive` for better responses, but we are only guessing without that information.